# Github API returning Error: Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: github, github-api, octokit-js

I am trying to hit our enterprise github API endpoint to retrieve the app installation details.

I get the following error while hitting the API from local/postman

Error: Unable to get local issuer certificate.

However, works fine in browser.

I tried adding user-agent as my app name, but to no avail.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually see that when doing a `curl` to a server for which I did not add the root CA/intermediate CA.
All I have to do then is reference those CAs (as a bundle file listing both root and intermediate CAs) in `~/.curlrc`.
You can get them with an [`openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect yourServer:443 < /dev/null`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368148/7490)

Those same CAs are generally already registered in the truststore of your browser, which is why it is working fine there.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks 